# highcharts - copy and paste the data on chart

Tags: excel, highcharts

Does Highcharts allows copy and paste with mouse drag selection? or any plugin that allows the same function?

I want 1. drag the chart area with mouse
       2. ctrl+c
       3. ctrl+v on the excel or any kind of text editor
       4. data of chart shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Highcharts (or any of its plugins) **doesn't support** that kind of functionality.

You can share the idea of implementing that here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Answer (score 0):

You can export to excel, see below example

```
https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get the data without downloading it?

Comment: you can access data from the chart component. Give some idea about your code